# How can I avoid a partition key from a too large size

Tags: cassandra

The partition size should not be greater than 10 MB (its recommended). How can I avoid this ?

I can use 2 Partition keys, but I can't query them, it does not fit in my query.

If you have 2 partition keys, and you execute a query, you have to call both partition keys like this:

```
user_id = partition key
post_id = partition key

SELECT * FROM posts WHERE user_id = 1 AND post_id = 1;
```

If you use this, you get an error because you don't call post_id

```
SELECT * FROM posts WHERE user_id = 1;
```

But I don't need post_id in my query or user_id I only always need one of them but not both. So how I avoid now the partition size ?

Comment: Read bucketing if that can help you.

Comment: you can add for example, year (or year & month) as an additional bucketing column - because you'll primarily show the posts based on some timing, then it may work for you

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can have table design like below -

```
CREATE TABLE user_post_by_month (
userid int,
year int,
month int,
postid int, 
post text,
PRIMARY KEY ((userid,year,month),postid);
```

This design will not create a wide row. You can fetch the post by user for a particular month. If you are expecting too many post for a user in a month, you can add another bucket, for example a week.

```
CREATE TABLE user_post_by_week (
userid int,
year int,
month int,
week int,
postid int, 
post text,
PRIMARY KEY ((userid,year,month,week),postid);
```